How can I set a python path to my workspace on vscode on Mac
I am trying to follow a Python for dummies book and it tells me to use 3 dots in the Code -> Settings -> Preferences -> Json settings and copy some code over somewhere but I’m really just lost as the latest vscode doesn’t have those 3 dots.
I have simply tried to follow the instructions in the book but I fear it may be outdated because there are no 3 dots to select json settings from. I have tried asking A.I. and I get some solutions but as someone new to this it looks like there are infinite ways to get things done and I just want to follow the book but it’s outdated apparently!

isbn and page number etc of the python for dummies please
